# pulseaudio under awesome wm

Tags: ubuntu, awesome-wm, pulseaudio

I try run pulseaudio under awesome in manual way.
(Ubuntu Mate 18.04 on gpd pocket)

A use command

```
 pulseaudio --start -vvv
```

and have error "Daemon startup failed", and not other errors.

Try using:

```
systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.socket
```

and other recommendations from 
 https://askubuntu.com/questions/15223/how-can-i-restart-pulseaudio-without-having-to-logout.

Answer (score 0):

In mate it start correctly, so hack solution have been found. It is need to run:

```
systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.socket
pasystray
```

It is magically run pulseaudio.
But I still don't understand how to run in manual and where is error.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to run `pulseaudio`:

1. System wide
2. Per user (`systemctl --user`)

In any case, looks like you're running it manually via a terminal, are you using a customized configuration? Try:

```sh
$ kill $(pidof pulseaudio)
$ pulseaudio --daemonize=false -vvv
```

If you want it to start automatically at login (though I think it starts running when an application triggers audio), you need to enable it via `systemd`, as in:

```sh
$ sudo systemctl disable pulseaudio
$ sudo systemctl stop pulseaudio
$ systemctl --user enable pulseaudio
# should create a link from /usr/lib/... to $HOME/.local/...
$ systemctl --user start pulseaudio
```

**NOTE**: If you're running per user, some `dbus` listeners won't have default names (or namespaces?) and some libraries/widgets will not work, like [pulseaudio_widget](https://luarocks.org/modules/stefano-m/pulseaudio_widget).

Answer (score 0):

What is needed is the **start-pulseaudio-x11** application

Answer (score -1):

I have this in my zshrc (I guess it can work in bash too, but I didn't try):

```
function getalsa() {echo $( \
    lsof +D /dev -F rt \
    | awk '/^p/ {pid=$1} /^t/ {type=$1} /^r0x(74|e)..$/ && type == "tCHR" {print pid}' \
    | cut -c 2- \
    | uniq \
)}
```

This way you can do:

```
getalsa | xargs kill
```

before pulse starts. This helps reliability a little. Otherwise sometime pulse even starts, but wont (ever) be able to gain access to the sound card.

Usually the answer was to uninstall Pulse, but this is no longer possible since Firefox and a bunch of other apps dropped "raw" Alsa support.